# Google Map Android v2 : Snapshot fails with bitmap size is zero

Tags: android, google-maps, bitmap, google-maps-android-api-2, snapshot

**I want to populate an ImageView with a Google Map v2 snapshot.**

Short summary:

Do I still need to inflate a Maps XML instance?

Do I need to use a Maps fragment?

Do I want to create a Maps instance programatically and just take a snapshot?

My thought was to create a Maps instance programatically, size it appropriately (say 200x200), and take a snapshot.  However, my snapshot routine always crashes with **"Bitmap must be > 0 in height and width"**.

Is this the wrong approach??

XML would be something like this:

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
        <ImageView android:id="@+id/location_card_map"
            android:layout_width="match_parent" 
            android:layout_height="match_parent" 
            android:contentDescription="Location"
            android:clickable="true"/>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Map class:

```
    private ManagerMaps(Context context)
    {
        mContext = context;
        mSharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
        initializeMaps();
    }
...
            private void initializeMaps()
            {
                LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(mContext);
                layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
                layout.setLayoutParams(new  LinearLayout.LayoutParams(200,200));//(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
                GoogleMapOptions options = new GoogleMapOptions();
                options.camera(new CameraPosition(new LatLng(0, 0), 1, 0, 0));

                // Create the MapView programmatically
                mMapView = new MapView(mContext, options);
                layout.addView(mMapView);
                    mMapView.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(200,200));        
                mMapView.onCreate(null);
                mMapView.onResume();
        //      setContentView(layout);        

                // Gets to GoogleMap from the MapView and does initialization stuff
                mMap = mMapView.getMap();
                if(mMap == null)
                {
                    Log.d("AppDebug", "MAP IS NULL ********");
                    return;
                }
                mMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true);
                mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

                // Needs to call MapsInitializer before doing any CameraUpdateFactory calls
                try {
                    MapsInitializer.initialize(mContext);
                } catch (GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }

            public void captureMapScreen() 
            {
                SnapshotReadyCallback callback = new SnapshotReadyCallback() {

                    @Override
                    public void onSnapshotReady(Bitmap snapshot) {
                        try {
                            FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(
                                    Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                                            + "/MapScreenShot"
                                            + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".png");

                            snapshot.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, out);
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                };
                mMap.snapshot(callback);  // crashes in bitmap thread here with height/width zero
            }
```

Calling method:

```
                ManagerMaps maps = ManagerMaps.getInstance(getActivity());
                maps.captureMapScreen();
```

EDIT:

Crash happens on: mMap.snapshot(callback);

**LogCat**

```
10-22 01:36:44.300: E/AndroidRuntime(29292): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-3366
10-22 01:36:44.300: E/AndroidRuntime(29292): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: width and height must be > 0
10-22 01:36:44.300: E/AndroidRuntime(29292):    at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:695)
10-22 01:36:44.300: E/AndroidRuntime(29292):    at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:674)
10-22 01:36:44.300: E/AndroidRuntime(29292):    at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:641)
10-22 01:36:44.300: E/AndroidRuntime(29292):    at maps.ag.ca.a(Unknown Source)
10-22 01:36:44.300: E/AndroidRuntime(29292):    at maps.ag.av.run(Unknown Source)
10-22 01:36:44.300: E/AndroidRuntime(29292):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google Maps (here in 2022) still throws a non-sensical createBitmap() instead of some error like 'Map-view size 0, please postpone snapshot til after layout...'

```
Crash: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: width and height must be > 0
    at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:969)
    at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:948)
    at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:915)
    at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.impl.a.d(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@224312019@22.43.12 (040400-0):2)
    at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.impl.bh.run(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@224312019@22.43.12 (040400-0):1)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:762)
```

I solved the problem on my end by delaying snapshot till after both layout has happened and map has been set via onMapReady:

```kotlin
import android.graphics.Bitmap
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.View
import androidx.core.view.doOnNextLayout
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment
import dk.bnr.androidbooking.extensions.iterateAndClear

class Map : SupportMapFragment(), OnMapReadyCallback {
    private val pendingOnAvailableBeforeRendering = mutableListOf<() -> Unit>()
    private var isLaidOut: Boolean = false // we have a size for the map - this is required for camera changes
    private var isMapAvailable: Boolean = false // available (onMapReady) but possibly not loaded yet, don't do animation stuff yet
    private lateinit var googleMap: GoogleMap    
    
    private inline val isMapReadyForCameraChange
        get() = isMapAvailable && isLaidOut // maybe also include isMapLoaded

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        view.doOnNextLayout {
            isLaidOut = true
            // GoogleMap may not be ready yet, so this also waits for GoogleMap ready
            executePendingActions()
        }
    }

    override fun onMapReady(googleMap: GoogleMap) {
        executePendingActions()
    }

    private fun executePendingActions() {
        if (isMapReadyForCameraChange) {
            pendingOnAvailableBeforeRendering.iterateAndClear {
                it()
            }
        }
    }

    private fun executeWhenReady(action: () -> Unit) {
        if (isMapReadyForCameraChange) action()
        else pendingOnAvailableBeforeRendering.add(action)
    }

    fun snapshot(action: (Bitmap?) -> Unit) {
        executeWhenReady {
            val view = this.view
            // This is hopefully not necessary, but I want to be sure, so we avoid createBitmap crash. It would make sense to log error if this view isn't ready
            if (view != null && view.width != 0 && view.height != 0) {
                googleMap.snapshot { bitmap: Bitmap? ->
                    action(bitmap)
                }
            } else {
                // TODO Log error
                action(null)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is  caused by an unfortunate combination of the automatic scaling of drawable resources in Android and very small drawables.

If, for example, your app only provides drawable-xhpdi resources, they need to be downsized to fit lower density screens. This is done automatically by Android if you don't provide these resources yourself.

The scale of display densities is set to be like this:

xhdpi: 2.0
hdpi: 1.5
mdpi: 1.0
ldpi: 0.75

Sometimes Unfortunately, when providing these resources as xhdpi and scaling them down, the pixel size can be truncated to 0. There is no guard in place for this and Android will fail to create a Bitmap with that dimension and crash showing `IllegalArgumentException: width and height must be > 0`

But I am Not Sure About Your case. So Please update Your question With LogCat.

update it lyk:

```
public void captureMapScreen() {
        SnapshotReadyCallback callback = new SnapshotReadyCallback() {

            @Override
            public void onSnapshotReady(Bitmap snapshot) {
                try {
                    mView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
                    Bitmap backBitmap = mView.getDrawingCache();
                    Bitmap bmOverlay = Bitmap.createBitmap(
                            backBitmap.getWidth(), backBitmap.getHeight(),
                            backBitmap.getConfig());
                    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bmOverlay);
                    canvas.drawBitmap(snapshot, new Matrix(), null);
                    canvas.drawBitmap(backBitmap, 0, 0, null);
                    FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(
                            Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                                    + "/MapScreenShot"
                                    + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".png");

                    bmOverlay.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, out);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        };

        mMap.snapshot(callback);

    }
```

Use  `snapshot.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, out);`For screenshot of map  and avoid Code

```
mView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
Bitmap backBitmap = mView.getDrawingCache();
Bitmap bmOverlay = Bitmap.createBitmap(
backBitmap.getWidth(), backBitmap.getHeight(),
backBitmap.getConfig());
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bmOverlay);
canvas.drawBitmap(snapshot, new Matrix(), null);
canvas.drawBitmap(backBitmap, 0, 0, null);
```

Comment: Thanks.  Updated with logcat.  Crash happens in a thread spawned from the "snapshot" call.

Comment: Thanks.  But I gave up on this approach.  I just used an actual map and disabled all scrolling and zooming, making it appear as if it were static.